# Custom toolbar template - fatal error on home page

Tags: toolbar, fatal-error

I want to have different templates for top and bottom toolbar, so in

```
\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
```

I use

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

instead of `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>`

**In Home page** I have

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

This works except Home page:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in
>   app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml
>   on line 34

What I can do to display products at home page with different top and bottom toolbars?

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I fixed problem.

I deleted `{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` from content of home page and added in home page to Desigh->Page Layout in the block  this:

```
 <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>5</category_id></action>
         <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" >
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
</block>
```

Comment: feel free to accept this answer if it is now working for you